# Outputing and Inputting Binary data C

Tags: c, file-io, matrix, binary-data

I'm trying to output and input a 2 dimensional array to binary.

My two dimensional array is contained within the following structure

```
typedef struct matrep {
    unsigned rows, columns;
    double *data;
} MATRIX;
```

and I've created the following function to output the whole structure

```
void matrix_writebinary(MATRIX *mat,FILE *fp)     
{
    int a=mat->rows,b=mat->columns;
    fwrite(&a,sizeof(int),1,fp);
    fwrite(&b,sizeof(int),1,fp);
    fwrite(mat->data,sizeof( double ) * a * b,1,fp);
    rewind(fp);
}
```

and the following function to input the structure

```
MATRIX *matrix_readbinary(MATRIX *mat,FILE *fp)     
{
    MATRIX matrix;
    MATRIX *ptr;
    ptr=&matrix;
    int a,b;

    double *tempptr=ptr->data;
    fread(&a,sizeof(int),1,fp);
    fread(&b,sizeof(int),1,fp);

    for ( int i=0; i < a; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j=0; j < b; j++ )
        {
            double value=0.0;     
            fread(&value,sizeof(double),1,fp);
            *(tempptr++)=value;
        }
    }

    rewind(fp);
    matrix.rows=a;
    matrix.columns=b;
    return(ptr);
}
```

I have checked that `mat->rows` and `mat->columns` have been both inputted and outputted correctly using a `printf` function, but when it reaches the line

```
*(tempptr++)=value;
```

in the code I get a segmentation error which tells me that I'm confusing my pointers.
I don't think the issue lies in opening  closing or manipulating files outside the function as I've succsessfully outputted the file and inputted it with fprintf and fscanf.

Could anyone help me sort out my pointers?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't allocated any memory for the data. You need to add the allocation:

```
ptr->data = malloc(sizeof(double) * ptr->rows * ptr->columns);
double *tempptr = ptr->data;

/* ... */
```

Moreover, you mustn't return the address of a temporary! So the matrix itself needs to be allocated dynamically, too:

```
MATRIX * ptr = malloc(sizeof(MATRIX));
```

You can read into `&ptr->rows` and `&ptr->columns` directly, no need for the intermediate variables. You can also read all the data in one go.

Putting it all together:

```
MATRIX *matrix_readbinary(FILE * fp)
{
    MATRIX * ptr = malloc(sizeof(MATRIX));

    fread(&ptr->rows, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, fp)
    fread(&ptr->columns, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, fp)

    ptr->data = malloc(sizeof(double) * ptr->rows * ptr->columns);

    fread(ptr->data, sizeof(double), ptr->rows * ptr->columns, fp)

    return ptr;
}
```

I wouldn't recommend passing in a `MATRIX` pointer, since that would require you to provide some half-baked matrix structure without allocated data memory, and you'd be in a responsibility nightmare.

Don't forget the corresponding clean-up function:

```
void matrix_free(MATRIX * mat)
{
    free(mat->data);
    free(mat);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, what you're saying makes sense, I didn't realise that I hadn't allocated memory. However when I try the function I get 2 errors, "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'MATRIX*'" in the line 'MATRIX * ptr = malloc(sizeof(MATRIX));' and "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'double*'" in the line ptr->data = malloc(sizeof(double) * ptr->rows * ptr->columns);

Comment: I thought you said you are writing C. You must have been lying, because what you describe is C++! :-) (It's important to say clearly which language you're writing in. In C++ the entire code is terrible and I would have done something completely different.)

Comment: Really sorry to be a pain, but having made the changes you suggested the programme still shuts down due to a segmentation fault

Comment: aah, well i thought I was only using c constructions, i must be doing c++ sorry about that :S

Comment: @Leavenotrace: Sorry, there was a bug in the `data` read line - no `&`! I also rewrote it to use the "number of elements" field in a tasteful way.

Comment: It works, thanks so much, I may be able to keep some of my hair now :D